# Making a set data type with list data structure in Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures, set

> Write insert and member operations in Haskell. Make sure that in ML
>   and Haskell your Set data type is distinct from a list. In Haskell,
>   define your Set type to be an instance of classes Eq and Show.

```
let setAdd l n = if (elem l n) then l else l ++ [n]
let setMember l i = l !! i
```

The code I written above just makes it have functions that perform on lists.

Is there a way to make this into a class? Sorry, I'm just learning functional programming. Is there a way to actually make a Set class that has member variables with such as a list?

Comment: Keep in mind that Haskell classes are not OOP classes. Indeed, OOP classes are _types_, while Haskell classes are not types. E.g. you can't have a variable `x` of "type" `Show` or `Eq`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data type here is `[a]`, which already has such instances available, including `Eq` and `Show` (that by the way do the right thing).

If you want to have write your own instances, you should `newtype` the underlying type, in a fashion similar to:

```
newtype Set a = Set { getSet :: [a] }
```

Then you can write:

```
instance Show a => Show (Set a) where
    show (Set a) = ...

instance Eq a => Eq (Set a) where
    Set a == Set b = ...
```